# Declaring extern structures in header file in C

Tags: c, struct, extern

I found some code that made me a bit intrigued: there is a header file declaring only structures that are being used in code for an embedded system written in C.

This is an example of code in the header:

```
#ifdef _structures_h_
 
extern struct{
    uint16_t  State_ON;
    uint16_t  State_OFF;
    uint16_t  State_HI;    
    uint16_t  Counter;
}Switch;

#endif


#ifndef _structures_h_
#define _structures_h_

struct{
    uint16_t  State_ON;
    uint16_t  State_OFF;
    uint16_t  State_HI;    
    uint16_t  Counter;
}Switch;

#endif
```

In the source files that make use of those structures, in some of them, the inclusion is done like this:

```
#define _structures_h_
#include "structures.h"
```

In others there is just the inclusion of the header file as shown below:

```
#include "structures.h"
```

- My doubt is, is there some reason for declaring the structures in both ways in the same header file?
- Is there any difference or relevant impact in coding declaring the same struct as extern or not in a header filer?

This is the first time that I have found such a situation and I was not able to find a reasonable explanation for using this.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh Please do not use comment section to give answers. As you can see in actual answers, your comment is incorrect. Please remove it.

Comment: Thinking about this code, I conjecture the author of the header was inexperienced with C and was not aware there are better solutions. Giving the structure type a name (with a tag or a `typedef`) would have enabled both declaring the object (unconditionally) and defining it (conditionally), so the header could have be written more cleanly, without repeating the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the two code sections is that, in the first (the one that has the `extern` keyword), the structure variable is *declared* but not *defined*. That is, the code specifies that the `Switch` variable is **defined elsewhere** (in another translation unit). However, in the second section, the `Switch` variable is formally declared **and defined** – or, at least, *tentatively* defined; that tentative definition will become an *actual* definition if/when the compilation of the translation unit completes with no other *full* definition (i.e., one with an initializer) occurring.

In that second conditional block, the definition of the `_structures_h_` token is **very** strange; and, unless there is more to the header than you have shown, I can really see no purpose for it:

1. If the header is included multiple times by a **single TU**, then, with or without that definition, there will be a case of redefinition of the `Switch` variable with different types (even though those types have exactly *equivalent* definitions, they are still separate types); that redefinition is an error.
2. If the header is included by **multiple TUs**, then the definition of the macro in one will not "carry through" to any others, so you will still (potentially) have multiple instances of the `Switch` variable from each of the TUs that include the header without first *themselves* defining the `_structures_h_` token.

But I would agree with you and the other answerer that code like this is both confusing and error-prone: For example, using that header in multiple translation units *without a preceding `_structures_h_` definition* will cause multiple definitions of the `Switch` variable.

Also, rather than using the `#ifndef ...` block, a simple `#else` would suffice and make things clearer (IMHO).

Here's a shortened, annotated version of the header:

```c
#ifdef _structures_h_
extern struct {
    uint16_t  State_ON;
    uint16_t  State_OFF;
    uint16_t  State_HI;
    uint16_t  Counter;
} Switch; // Already defined elsewhere - just need the declaration
#else
struct {
    uint16_t  State_ON;
    uint16_t  State_OFF;
    uint16_t  State_HI;
    uint16_t  Counter;
} Switch; // Not yet defined, so we provide a "tentative" definition
#endif
```

Or, an even shorter way, which avoids the multiple specifications of the structure (and the errors that could lead to), is to define a separate 'linkage' macro that is either `extern` or nothing:

```
#ifdef _structures_h_
#define SW_LINKAGE extern
#else
#define SW_LINKAGE /*  */
#endif
SW_LINKAGE struct {
    uint16_t  State_ON;
    uint16_t  State_OFF;
    uint16_t  State_HI;
    uint16_t  Counter;
} Switch;
```

Comment: Very clarifying, I was thinking if it would have some advantage, but it has only disadvantages.
Indeed the complete code is very confusing, in some source files I saw that it was defining the _structures_h_, but there was no definition, but as it has a huge list of includes, the structure should be defined elsewhere in another file, what makes this code hard to read and understand.

Comment: The latter declaration of `Switch` is a tentative definition, not a definition. A tentative definition is not, in spite of its name, a definition, similarly to the way that a prospective employee on a job interview is not an employee. Repeating the tentative definition does not cause a multiple definition of `Switch` and is not, by itself, cause for an error. For example, the tentative definition `int x;` may be repeated indefinitely…

Comment: …  Repeating the tentative definition causes an error not because it is a multiple definition but because it redeclares `Switch` with a different type, because each occurrence of `struct { … }` is a definition of a new type.

Comment: @Eric As ever, you are both correct and precise! I have edited the post to (hopefully) embrace the points you have made. But having multiple "tentative definitions" of the same variable in different TUs will (IIRC) cause multiple instances of the variable at link time.

Comment: @AdrianMole: Re “But having multiple "tentative definitions" of the same variable in different TUs will (IIRC) cause multiple instances of the variable at link time”: I am not advocating the code that OP found, but that is implementation-dependent. A traditional Unix behavior was to coalesce multiple tentative definitions with zero or one regular definition. That was default GCC behavior before version 10 and is still supported with a switch.

Comment: FYI, the C standard leaves it undefined what happens if there are multiple definitions in different translation units, and this is why. It would have been easy to define the behavior to produce a link error. But this would have banned a traditional Unix behavior. So it was just left undefined, allowing implementations to choose. That is an example where “undefined behavior” is not “You screwed up, your program is bad” but “The C standard has no jurisdiction, you figure it out.”

Comment: The conditional `extern` is a kludgy solution. Using `typedef struct { … } SwitchStructure; extern SwitchStructure Switch;` followed by `SwitchStructure Switch = { 0 };` inside a `#if` … `#endif` would be nicer. Still uses `#if` but in a cleaner all-or-nothing way instead of with an additional macro modifying part of a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

This construction basically boils down to this:

**header.h**

```
#ifdef _structures_h_

extern struct {
  int  State_ON;
  int  State_OFF;
} Switch;

#endif

#ifndef _structures_h_
#define _structures_h_

struct {
  int  State_ON;
  int  State_OFF;
} Switch;

#endif
```

**file1.c**

```
#include "header.h"

void Function();

int main(void)
{
    Switch.State_ON = 2;
    Function();
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define _structures_h_
#include "header.h"

void Function()
{
    printf("Switch.State_ON = %d\n", Switch.State_ON);
}
```

This is pretty ugly because:

- in header.h the struct is repeated which is error prone
- it is unclear when and why we need to have `#define _structures_h_` before including header.h
- the whole thing is confusing as you have experienced yourself.

---

The usual way this is done looks like this:

**header.h**

```
#ifndef _structures_h_
#define _structures_h_

typedef struct {
  int  State_ON;
  int  State_OFF;
} SwitchStruct;

extern SwitchStruct Switch;   // declare the Switch variable so that anybody
                              // who includes header.h can use it
#endif
```

**file1.c**

```
#include "header.h"

SwitchStruct Switch;  // the one and only place where the variable
                      // Switch is defined
void Function();

int main(void)
{
    Switch.State_ON = 2;
    Function();
}
```

**file2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

void Function()
{
 // we can use Switch because it is declared in header.h
    printf("Switch.State_ON = %d\n", Switch.State_ON);
}
```